# "We were unable to decrypt the certificate id" - Paypal EWP asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, paypal, paypal-buttons

I have been trying for a while now to get this working.

I'm using source code from here... https://github.com/axefrog/XMerchant

I have uploaded a pub key to Paypal to generate a certificate in my sandbox account. I am passing the cert id into the html that is being encrypted.

But i keep getting the error "We were unable to decrypt the certificate id".

Has anyone had this issue before when trying to encrypt their own Paypal buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an explanation for this error. But i have found an alternative solution, using PayPals button manager SDK for .NET.

https://github.com/paypal/buttonmanager-sdk-dotnet/tree/v2.6.106

Its great!